# User Defined Function by JavaScript API for Excel

Tags: ms-office, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I have a library of functions written in JavaScript, for example `myfactorial(n)` can caculate the factorial of `n` in my way.

I would hope to develop an add-in by JavaScript API for Excel, such that once a user loads the add-in, they could use the embedded functions, e.g., write in a formula: `=myfactorial(A2)` or `=callfunction("myfactorial", A2)`. In short, it is about supporting User Defined Functions by JavaScript API for Excel, I guess they are asking the same thing [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/6936956-add-user-defined-function-support-to-the-apps-for).

So, does any know how is the progress? Otherwise, is there some workaround that we could do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for this question! User-defined functions are a central part of Excel customization today. We're working on a solution that will bring those capabilities across all our modern Excel platforms. We're still figuring out the design, so unfortunately I don't have a timeline or details to share right now. I'll give an update in a few months.

-Michael, PM for Office add-ins

Update 11/6/17: JavaScript custom functions in Excel are now available in Developer Preview for anyone to try: https://aka.ms/customfunctions

Comment: Any news regarding the subject of creating user defined functions  ?

Comment: We've continued our work in this area, and it's still a priority for our team. We're looking forward to sharing more but right now I don't have announcements about the feature or release dates.

Comment: @MichaelSaunders It seems that there is some update?

Comment: Update: it's live in Developer Preview! Please try it and send your feedback: https://aka.ms/customfunctions

Comment: is this also available for Excel Online? (I could not find the docs explicitly stating that [I am still trying to learn to read the docs, but I am not so good at it])

Comment: I just got an email which told me "Custom functions are officially in Preview! Try them! more info in https://aka.ms/customfunctions". But on that page `Deployment via the Office 365 Admin Portal and AppSource are not yet enabled.` is still there. So today developers still can NOT submit add-ins with custom functions?